# How to show error when user enter more than `one` or 1 character?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using `ant design` for my application.
https://ant.design/components/table/
I am facing one validation issue. I implemented  table in my demo .when I click `edit` button it shows me `input field`

I am able to add validation of `required`  .so empty is not allowed .but I want user only enter `one` or  1 character inside the `input` field else it shows an error.

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-tesla-1nwph

```
return (
      <td {...restProps}>
        {editing ? (
          <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
            {getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: `Please Input ${title}!`
                }
              ],
              initialValue: record[dataIndex]
            })(getInput())}
          </Form.Item>
        ) : (
          children
        )}
      </td>
    );
  };
```

form error
https://ant.design/components/form/

[image]

Comment: use maxLength attribute on input field?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP wants the literal options "1" or "one", in which case the pattern attribute would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to add validation of required .so empty is not allowed .but I want user only enter one or 1 character inside the input field else it shows an error.

If you are saying "only the literal `1` or `one` should be valid inside the input", you can use

```js
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: `Please Input ${title}!`
                },
                {
                  pattern: /^(1|one)$/,
                  message: "Only 1 or one are valid"
                }
              ],
```

Othwerwise if it is length you can use `max` property. A list of all validation rules can be seen here: https://ant.design/components/form/?locale=en-US#Validation-Rules